# Backing up broken android device

Tags: usb, backup

I have an android device running KitKat 4.4.2 (not rooted; developer stuff turned on) and I shattered the digitizer. I can still see what's on the screen but I can't interact with it<sup>1</sup>. I tried using `adb` to back it up, but I was unable to press the "confirm" button on the screen. Is there anything I can do now [i.e. without getting a USB OTG cable and a mouse]? I'm comfortable w/ ADB and the command line if necessary.

<sup>1</sup><sub>I could get an OTG USB cable and connect a keyboard/mouse and use that to install a backup app, etc. but I'm hoping there's an easier way.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Install a vnc server on the phone through adb and then you can connect to it.

Comment: Can you suggest a VNC server that you can set up and run without touching the screen?